# Strongswan to OpenBSD isakmpd IPSec VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

At my end I have a StrongSwan installation, connecting to an IPSec VPN hosted by an OpenBSD box running stock isakmpd. The OpenBSD box already hosts multiple other associations, but the StrongSwan box is a new client.

The credentials I have (an x509 certificate) have successfully be used on a Windows box with TheGreenBow as a client, and I've nearly got it working with StrongSwan. It successfully raises a connection and organises a security association. However, no traffic is actually flowing over it - and it doesn't appear to be using the value set under `leftsourceip`. `ipsec statusall` gives the following:

```
vpn{1}:  AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying in 25 minutes
vpn{1}:  192.168.1.6/32 === 172.17.1.0/24
```

With `192.168.1.6` being my local IP. `leftsourceip` is set to `172.18.1.97`. My understanding is that `192.168.1.6/32` displayed by the status command should actually be `172.18.1.97/32` - almost like it's ignoring the value set?

Is there anything else that might be causing an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leftsourceip` is only used for dynamic assignment of configuration attributes (including IP addresses) via *mode config* or IKEv2 configuration payloads. strongSwan won't install that address locally if *mode config* is not used. The [strongSwan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp) has more on this.

If you want to use a specific IP address inside the tunnel, just install it on one of the local interfaces (could even be `lo`).  Then use that address in your `leftsubnet` setting e.g. `leftsubnet=172.18.1.97/32`.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick! Did previously have a look at the virtual IP page  - makes a bit more sense now...